# Angular. Not able to show and display row number in the first column for dynamic table using Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, numbers, row, record

I have been trying to add a row number or record number to my material table. The first column should show 1,2,3,4,5, etc. Problem is I am using dynamic table (generate using ngFor) because I would not know the type of records that is going to be returned. My table is sortable and will have filtering function. This constraint meant that I cannot tie the row number to individual record.

The best I have managed to do is a hack. Overwrite the contents of the first column with row number but this solution is not ideal. There should be a solution somewhere but I cannot find one.

Would appreciate if someone can help.

```
<div id="table-wrapper" >
<mat-table #myResultTable  [dataSource]="resultTable" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8" 
    cdkDropListGroup >

    <ng-container  *ngFor="let columnHeader of columnsInTable; let colIndex = index" 
        [matColumnDef]="columnHeader.field" >

        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header>

                {{columnHeader.field}}

        </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let rec; let num=index” >

            <div style="word-break: break-word;" > 
                {{rec[colIndex]}}
            </div>
    
        </mat-cell>

    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row class="colheader" *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; " ></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" > </mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

Comment: Can you explain Why you need here *ngFor for mat-table? without *ngFor you can also displys all table dataSource records too.

Comment: I am querying the server which will reply with an array of array of string. As such, sometimes, my mat-table will have 10 records of 5 columns. Sometimes it will have 8 records with 7 columns. That is why use *ngFor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add a new column 'num' with `<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i=index"> {{i+1}} </td>` and add to displayedColumns

You can use *ngIf="!first" if you want a separate columns.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="num">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i=index"> {{i+1}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns;let first=first">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!first" [matColumnDef]="column">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzhq3m?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html)

Comment: Ah, your solution work. But does not seem to work in my scenario. I hit problem with "Could not find column with id xxxx" where xxxx is the first column. Could it be that I am using this command : this.resultTable = new MatTableDataSource(this.sqlresponse.tableResultArray);

Comment: @simonthismyvoice, take account you need that "displayedColumns" must add a new value, in my case 'num', a kind of : `this.displayedColumns=['num',...this.displayedColumns]`

Comment: I found the problem. Addition of 'num' was not my problem. I did add it. More that part where I have this: "let columnHeader of columnsInTable". You see, columnHeader is an object. I got it sorted out. Thanks.